# Detect idle users and auto logout them in .NET Core 5 Razor pages

Tags: session, asp.net-core-mvc, session-cookies, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-5.0

I am working on a ASP.NET Core 5 web application using Razor pages.

My task to detect idle users (being idle for 5 minutes) and auto logout them from the application. They need to login again to continue.

I've used this code in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    options.Cookie.Name = "cookie_name";
});
```

How can I detect users idle time and logout them?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could set as below:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        // Cookie settings
        
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.LoginPath = ".....";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "....";
        
    });
```

idle users have to login again after 5 minutes,and if The SlidingExpiration is set to true , a new cookie with a new expiration time woould be re-issued any time it processes a request which is more than halfway through the expiration window.you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.cookieauthenticationoptions.slidingexpiration?view=aspnetcore-1.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Thank you @RuiKai, for this answer. I need to detect users with no activity for certain times and logged out from the application. `options.ExpireTimeSpan` counts the time from the cookie is created. It automatically expires whether the user is idle or not. I do not want that. I have done this using jQuery, and it's working as per my requirements.